# How to detect corrupted images (PNG, JPG) in Java

Tags: java, image, javax.imageio

I need to detect if the image file is corrupted in Java. I'm working only with PNG, JPG images. Is this possible to do with Sanselan? Or can it be done with ImageIO? I've tried using ImageIO.read seems like it works. But I'm not sure if it can detect every kind of errors in images. I'd like to know what's the best practice.

Comment: I would suggest that the only way to detect *every* kind of error in an image (where "error" is defined as any discrepancy which causes imperfect behaviour) is to go ahead and use the image.  It's entirely possible for an image to suffer a corruption which nonetheless results in a valid file, albeit one with "the wrong pixels".  It may be useful to think very specifically about what it is you want to detect.

Comment: ImageIO can detect truncated PNG with an exception thrown, but for JPG that is truncated, I can't get it to throw an exception.

Answer (score 16):

Here is my solution that would handle checking for broken GIF, JPG and PNG.  It checks for truncated JPEG using the JPEG EOF marker, GIF using an index out of bounds exception check and PNG using an EOFException

```
public static ImageAnalysisResult analyzeImage(final Path file)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
    final ImageAnalysisResult result = new ImageAnalysisResult();

    final InputStream digestInputStream = Files.newInputStream(file);
    try {
        final ImageInputStream imageInputStream = ImageIO
                .createImageInputStream(digestInputStream);
        final Iterator<ImageReader> imageReaders = ImageIO
                .getImageReaders(imageInputStream);
        if (!imageReaders.hasNext()) {
            result.setImage(false);
            return result;
        }
        final ImageReader imageReader = imageReaders.next();
        imageReader.setInput(imageInputStream);
        final BufferedImage image = imageReader.read(0);
        if (image == null) {
            return result;
        }
        image.flush();
        if (imageReader.getFormatName().equals("JPEG")) {
            imageInputStream.seek(imageInputStream.getStreamPosition() - 2);
            final byte[] lastTwoBytes = new byte[2];
            imageInputStream.read(lastTwoBytes);
            if (lastTwoBytes[0] != (byte)0xff || lastTwoBytes[1] != (byte)0xd9) {
                result.setTruncated(true);
            } else {
                result.setTruncated(false);
            }
        }
        result.setImage(true);
    } catch (final IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        result.setTruncated(true);
    } catch (final IIOException e) {
        if (e.getCause() instanceof EOFException) {
            result.setTruncated(true);
        }
    } finally {
        digestInputStream.close();
    }
    return result;
}

public class ImageAnalysisResult {
    boolean image;
    boolean truncated;
    public void setImage(boolean image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    public void setTruncated(boolean truncated) {
        this.truncated = truncated;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the two clauses of the JPEG condition check be connected with logical OR instead of AND?

Comment: Can you link this class ImageAnalysisResult

Comment: Could you include all the import statements in your answer please

Comment: I built a little library based on this answer since I was in need as well! 
hope it may help: https://github.com/lamba92/KImageCheck

Answer (score 6):

If the image in JPEG, use this:

```
JPEGImageDecoder decoder = new JPEGImageDecoder(new FileImageSource(f) ,new FileInputStream(f));
decoder.produceImage();
```

if it throws an exception; this means the image is corrupted.

for the other cases; just use `new ImageIcon(file)` to check the validity.

Comment: It works fine, if it is not valid jpeg image then it'll throw ImageFormatException. Is there any way to check whether mp4 file is corrupted or not ??

Comment: Use `PNGImageDecoder` for `PNG` formats and `GifImageDecoder` for `gif` formats.

Comment: `import sun.awt.image.JPEGImageDecoder` causes this error on Java 9+: `Package 'sun.awt.image' is declared in module 'java.desktop', which does not export it to module 'MODULE_NAME'`!

Answer (score 2):

below code validates .jpeg, .png, .jpg, .tiff images in java

```java
public boolean isValidImage(File f) {
  boolean isValid = true;
  try {
    ImageIO.read(f).flush();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    isValid = false;
  }
  return isValid;
}
```

Comment: In the case of JPG (I haven't tested other formats), this method only works if the content has no header. So it fails to detect incomplete images with header. In that case, `Archimides`'s answer works best as it verifies that the image is complete to the end.

Answer (score 1):

If the image can't be parsed the file is corrupt, otherwise the file should be valid but contains the wrong pixels as Andrzej pointed out. Detecting that might be quite hard if you can't define how you would find "wrong" pixels.

If you have information on the base image, e.g. a histogram or even the original pixels, you might try and compare those with the read image. Note, however, that due to compression there might be some errors, so you'd need to add some tolerance value.

An additional side note: Sanselan won't read JPEG images so you'd have to use ImageIO here.