# Not a JEPG file JAI, End Of Image, premature end of input file

Tags: java, jai

While loading a Jpeg image using JAI I encounter an exception:

> Caused by: com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.util.ImagingException: Unable to process image stream, incorrect format.
>       ... 43 more
>   Caused by: com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.ImageFormatException: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xff 0xd9
>       at sun.awt.image.codec.JPEGImageDecoderImpl.readJPEGStream(Native Method)

Looking at the hex it does in fact have a 0xff 0xd9 block in the file stream well above the end. According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure):

> EOI   0xFF, 0xD9  none    End Of Image

However I know I can open this file in any image editor.  If I re-save in paint.net editor at 95% comprepssion the block goes away (I'm assuming because this block is in the header and paint.net rewrites the header when saving)

I know I can detect it via a simple bytecheck https://stackoverflow.com/a/10069478/51841

Is there either

- A way to open and re-save the image in java such that it wont be an issue for the rest of JAI (such that I get a RenderedOp at the end)
- A way to make JAI read the image in-spite of this header (as most image readers seem to do)
- A safe way to modify that binary block (ie, replace with another block)

Or does anyone have any more insight into this issue that I am missing?

Comment: may i know how u settle this issue?